# Sorting JSON data with Knockout .sort()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting, knockout.js

I can sort my data using Knockout's .sort(). But, when I try to sort dynamically on a user's click, the sort goes haywire. Here's my code:

```js
var patientReport = [{"first_name":"Lyle","last_name":"Erickson","patient_id":1000},{"first_name":"Janna","last_name":"Barr","patient_id":1001},{"first_name":"Shelly","last_name":"Delacruz","patient_id":1002},{"first_name":"Nissim","last_name":"Wong","patient_id":1003},{"first_name":"Yvonne","last_name":"Rocha","patient_id":1004},{"first_name":"Leo","last_name":"Holland","patient_id":1005},{"first_name":"Melinda","last_name":"Curtis","patient_id":1006},{"first_name":"Orlando","last_name":"Peters","patient_id":1007},{"first_name":"Miriam","last_name":"Bates","patient_id":1008},{"first_name":"Otto","last_name":"Hurley","patient_id":1009},{"first_name":"Doris","last_name":"Byrd","patient_id":1010}];

var myObservableArray = ko.observableArray(patientReport);

$('.sort_header').on('click', function() {
 var data = $(this).data('header');
 sortRows(data);
});

function sortRows(row) {
 myObservableArray.sort(
  function(left, right) {
   return left.row == right.row ? 0 : (left.row < right.row ? -1 : 1);
  }
 ); 
}
```

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: Why are you using jquery click and not knockout click?

Comment: Because I'm new to knockout. Appreciate any direction on the knockout way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `left[row]` rather than `left.row` (and the same for `right`). The way you have it you are trying to sort by a property actually called `"row"`. Using the square bracket syntax lets you use the property with the name specified by the *variable* `row`.

```
function sortRows(row) {
  myObservableArray.sort(
    function(left, right) {
      return left[row] == right[row] ? 0 : (left[row] < right[row] ? -1 : 1);
    }
  );    
}
```

Comment: Bingo, nnnnnn! Thanks.